# Delete values of an ArrayList<String> if it contains words other than numbers

Tags: java, android, string

I want to remove all values from the list except those contains only Numbers. like 123222

```
 private ArrayList<String> filters(ArrayList<String> resulting) {

    String regex = "[0-9]+"; 

    ArrayList<String> abc =resulting;

    for(String x : resulting)
    {
        if(!x.matches(regex))
        {
            abc.remove(x);
        }
    }
    return abc;
}
```

I am passing this here..

```
 if (results != null) {
            options.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filters(results)));
        }
```

i have call it in `filters(results)`

but it is showing all words like hello , please.

Comment: You cannot modify a collection while iterating it. I suggest you not use the "enhanced" for loop and use the old one with an `Iterator`. The iterator instance has a `remove()` method that you might find useful.

Comment: Also, you will have a nasty side effect over the collection that somebody provided you by parameter. Maybe that is what you want, but if not I would recommend creating a new collection with only the elements that match the regular expression.

Comment: for that reason..i have initialize it to abc. i am removing abc not resulting? and please share some code.

Comment: String regex = "\\d+"; May help. Other idea it´s to remove by index instead of Object

Comment: @Nepster try with ArrayList<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>(resulting); for initialize abc

Comment: @Nepster `abc` points to the same underlying object as `resulting`. You are going to have to actually make a new object to avoid affecting the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
private ArrayList<String> filters(ArrayList<String> resulting) {

    String regex = "[0-9]+";
    // This regex also works
    String regex = "\\d+";

    ArrayList<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < resulting.size(); i++) {
        if(resulting.get(i).matches(regex)) {
            abc.add(resulting.get(i));
        }
    }
    return abc;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to declare what "x" is.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I would do:

```
private ArrayList<String> filters(ArrayList<String> parameter) {
    String regex = "\\d+"; 

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String x : parameter) {
        if(x.matches(regex)) {
            result.add(x);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This way you won't have any kind of side effect over the parameter provided.

Comment: Clean answer. Should be the accepted one if it works.

Comment: I would suggest a couple of minor improvements. 1. Initialize the result ArrayList to the size of the parameter.  2. Compile the regex Pattern 1 time (preferably as a constant).

Comment: That would indicate that you are continuing to use the original list and not the new list instance returned.

Comment: axierjhtjz and Claudio both are correct at one time i can accept one answer. I have accepted axierjhtz answer and give you upvote to equalize ..

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would work with Pattern and Matcher.
Just create a new Pattern.compile(regex) and a new Matcher(line).
Then loop over the Matcher while Matcher.find()

Comment: in fact the code should loke like so: 

Patter p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

while(m.find()){
 dosomething
}

Comment: `Matcher.find` and `String.match` perform 2 very different operations.